# jquerymobile - location.href - moving pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the location.href = "html page" to move one html page to another page. I want to pass some data when I move the pages. How to do it in? I am new bee to this one. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit

Why is this tagged jquery-mobile at all?

If you want to pass data to server-side script, you do it as always:

```
href="somesite.html?foo=bar&duck=swims"
href="somesite.php?foo=bar&duck=swims"
href="somesite.aspx?foo=bar&duck=swims"
```

If using jquery mobile you shouldn't change pages this way at all. Create links or use changePage() method.

Comment: Hi, I want to pass the "value" to javascript. Based on the "value", the next page will show. Any suggestion please. How to do it? still stuck up :(

Comment: 1. You are abusing the framework if you use location.href and it won't work properly. 2. If you make it work properly (with href or changePage) you will not need to pass any data to javascript because there's no page reload. `window.value='aaa'` will still be avaliable. But jquerymobile doesn't run scripts attached to the other page, so you have to change the way you use javascript with jquerymobile.

Comment: I will soon publish a tutorial on how to script pages and use jqm properly at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Naugtur. Your comments are very useful. I am waiting for the your tutorial.